# RecyclerView layout behaviour

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, accessibility

I'm working on an `AccessibilityService` which *visits* other apps layouts.

For example, if I have a custom layout, I'd precise the focus handling for each view in the XML, like this:

```xml
<View
...
android:nextFocusDown="@id/another_view_id"
android:nextFocusLeft="@id/another_view_id"
android:nextFocusRight="@id/another_view_id"
android:nextFocusUp="@id/another_view_id" />
```

When I used a `ListView` I defined the behaviour by sending some `KEYCODE_DPAD_UP` or `KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN` into the system with the aim of navigating through the layout.

Now I need to use a `RecyclerView` and I can't understand how exactly I can visit the view's items in the correct order.

**What I mean by the correct order:**

[image: What I mean by the correct order]

Can someone enlighten me on the way the layout order works with the `RecyclerView` ?

Comment: So RecyclerViews are built around the ViewHolder pattern. ListViews allowed for major inefficiencies that have been remedied by this. This, however, meant that managing position specific views from within the adapter became more difficult, as the views themselves were being recycled readily. Fortunately, the construction of a RecyclerView requires a `LayoutManager`. This LayoutManager will have a method called `findViewByPosition()`. This, in combination with `setNextFocus[Direction]()` methods on the respective views.

Comment: Currently, my project architecture works like this: There is different kind of Layout (ListView, App with tabs, GridView, RecyclerView) and I created, what I called, `Visitor`s for each of them. And they receive the `AccessibilityEvent` corresponding to themselves. Meaning that, *i.e.* my `ListView` has a `ListViewVisitor` which receive the item count and the current item selected index.

So, with this kind of architecture and your explanation, I can't access my LayoutManager and findviews, that's not how I can make it work. I need to rethink about it.

Answer (score 0):

It is the staggered list in recyclerview mode